# Django 2.1 - 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__name__'

Tags: python, django

I recently upgraded Django from 2.0.7 to 2.1.1, a new error occurs in which I get this error `'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__name__'`.

I'd like to understand if my fix is right and what caused this new error to happen, I couldn't find anything on the django release notes related to this issue, maybe I missed it.

**decorators.py**

```py
def auth0_login_required(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):

        if request.isAuthenticated or request.user.is_staff:
            pass
        else:
            raise Http404()
            
        return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
    wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = function.__name__ # ERROR HERE
    return wrap
```

How it is used, **views.py**:

```py
@method_decorator(auth0_login_required, name='dispatch')
class Dashboard(View):
    ...
```

For the fix I just removed `wrap.__name__ = function.__name__`, but I'm not sure if it'll break something else.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rather than manually copy things across, use the [`@functools.wraps()` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to handle this for you:

```
from functools import wraps

def auth0_login_required(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):

        if request.isAuthenticated or request.user.is_staff:
            pass
        else:
            raise Http404()

        return function(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrap
```

The `@wraps()` decorator (via the [`functools.update_wrapper()` function it calls](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper) knows how to handle `functools.partial` objects correctly (or rather, it can handle the fact that `functools.partial` objects have no `__name__` attribute).

It's fine that the wrapped `functools.partial()` object found on the `View` class doesn't have a `__name__` attribute, what's not fine is that you then don't copy that attribute at all even when you are decorating functions that do have the attribute. If you don't want to use `@wraps()` you'd have to manually copy the attribute across and handle the exception yourself:

```
try:
    wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
except AttributeError:
    pass
try:
    wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

but take into account that this doesn't copy the `__qualname__`, `__module__` and `__annotations__` attributes, doesn't handle any custom attributes set on `function` (which other decorators might rely on). `@functools.wraps()` does take care of all of those, plus it sets the `__wrapped__` attribute on the decorator wrapper function that [would let you unwrap the decorator again](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.unwrap).