# attributeerror 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__name__'

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-decorators

I am using Django 2.2 and Python 3.7, am trying to make a `decorators.py` function called `ajax_required` and am getting this error once I run the server:

```
 AttributeError 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

decorators.py

```
from django.http import Http404


    def ajax_required(function):
        def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if not request.is_ajax():
                raise Http404
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
        wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
        return wrap
```

Comment: Evidently you're trying to wrap a `functools.partial`, and they don't have a `__name__`. If you use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps), it'll handle that for you.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52271368/django-2-1-functools-partial-object-has-no-attribute-name)

Comment: So what do you suggest to be updated

Comment: Just FYI:  `getattr(function, '__name__', None)` would have worked instead of `function.__name__` and might be useful in other cases.

Answer (score 2):

I have gone through this link here [@functools.wraps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps)

I solved it by updating and the error was gone

```
from functools import wraps
from django.http import Http404


def ajax_required(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.is_ajax():
            raise Http404
        return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrap
```